# How to add a reference in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse

I have developed a little software in ACCESS/VBA. It dealt with Lotus Notes so in Visual Basic editor I just went to tools -> references and checked the **Lotus Notes Automation classes** which allowed me to work with it.

Now I wanna port this to Java. Last time i used java was about 4 years ago. I got my company to install Eclipse on my computer. I dont think i'll have trouble programming it because I come from a .net (C#) background.

HOWEVER, I can't seem to find a way to reference the LotusNotes classes through Eclipse. The class is a "tlb" file in the program files directory.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

1. Right click on your project and select **Properties** to open the Properties dialog.
2. Click on **Java Build Path** on the left navigation tree.
3. Select the **Libraries** tab on the right.
4. Add your Jars to the list.

   **Note:** *You can also add link to a class folder by clicking the **Add Class Folder** button on right.*

[image: Screenshot of the Properties Screen]

Comment: It is not a JAR file, it is a TLB located in programfiles folder. I believe it is a COM library. Not sure if i said that right